# How to use Angular module by require js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

i am little familiar with require js to load my js module dynamically. here i like to share my knowledge how i load my js module by require js.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
  <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load scripts/main.js after require.js loads. -->
  <script data-main="Scripts/main" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  Test
  <input type="button" id="btnLoadMoudle2" value="Load Module 2" />
</body>
</html>
```

### main.js

```
// For any third party dependencies, like jQuery, place them in the lib folder.

// Configure loading modules from the lib directory,
// except for 'app' ones, which are in a sibling
// directory.
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'Scripts',
});

// Start loading the main app file. Put all of
// your application logic in there.
//load module1 on page load and show message that module 1 i loaded
requirejs(['module1'], function (module1) {
  module1.Message();

  //attach click event handler that will show load module 2 dynamically at runtime not on page load check this using dom explorer
  document.getElementById('btnLoadMoudle2').addEventListener('click', function () {
     // load module 2 on click and show message
     requirejs(['module2'], function (module2)
    { module2.Message(); });
  }, false);
});
```

### module1.js

```
//this will be loaded on page load. 
define(function () {
  //Do setup work here

  return {
    Message: function () {
      alert('Module 1 Loaded');
    }
  }
});
```

### module2.js

```
//this will be loaded on button click
define(function () {

  return {
    Message: function () {
      alert('Module 2 Loaded');
    }
  }
});
```

Now my question is how to load angular multiple module and dependencies with require.js. i am new in angular. so i am looking for a easy sample code to start.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/ first hit on google

Comment: the url u gave looks bit complicated.

Comment: try this: http://leog.me/log/making-sense-of-requirejs-with-angularjs